# How can we integrate Jekyll to allow "not technical " to create and edit posts within an organization?

Tags: content-management-system, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

We maintain a website that contains a blog. 
This blog is generated through Jekyll. My problem is that I need another internal department to edit/create posts, but they have no idea about git or any command line.

I was wondering if any plugin / CMS framework could be implemented around Jekyll to allow such thing.

I've already read about prose.io, but I don't want to run through GitHub Pages since the blog is host in the same place as the website it refers to.

Thank for any help !

Comment: Can Jekyll publish straight HTML? If so, consider putting WordPress on the intranet, and capture the output in your build process. That avoids the need to ask people to use Markdown, whilst not exposing the WordPress install to the internet.

Comment: Perhaps this helps? <https://stackedit.io/> It's wonderful for writing in markdown. @halfer your idea is brilliant, but how can we do that? I mean, how to make WordPress "talk" to Jekyll? Yes, Jekyll outputs plain html.

Comment: I haven't done it, so it would require some research. WordPress output is available without templating in the RSS feed, so you could write something that captures that and puts it in the Jekyll input for templating. Or you could see if [this plugin](http://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/wordpress/) would help (not used it, just found by searching).

Answer (score 1):

You can use CloudCannon.com for easy editing and let CloudCannon sync your blog through FTP with your host. The result will be: the same hosting environment and a very user friendly CMS, which is designed specifically for Jekyll integration.

PS. You can use the free plan.

Comment: Yes. Note that CloudCannon has 'CMS for Jekyll' on its frontpage.

Comment: Great, thanks! I've made an update for readers' easy reference.